# Polish KDE translation in Kubuntu 13.10?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, translation, localization

How do I install new language in Kubuntu 13.10?
I've chosen Poland as my country but only English language is available.
I've already tried to search for "kde-l10n" in Muon (software center) but it found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be: KDE System Settings > Locale > Languages

Pick the Polish and move it to the right

[image]

There should be password query and the installation should start

[image]

At here, this is installing: calligra-l10n-pl, firefox-locale-pl, kde-l10n-pl, language-pack-pl, language-pack-pl-base.

Viewed from the dpkg.log:

```
grep install /var/log/dpkg.log
```

If the 'Available Languages' is empty you could try with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install calligra-l10n-pl firefox-locale-pl kde-l10n-pl language-pack-pl language-pack-pl-base
```